# Can you change amount of segments of the bevel later on?

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

Is there a way to change amount of segments after I already added the bevel? If not how am I supposed to control the shape of the mesh, if I changed my mind during my workflow. (I tried using subdiv, but in my case it gives a completely different effect )
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can change it right after the Ctrl B in the Operator box, or press F9, but as soon as you do the next action you'll loose the possibility to tweak the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't. Or not as flexibly as you would probably wish.

When doing a manual bevel with ctrl + B you can open a menu with all the options for the bevel with the F9 key tho this will not be accesible after you did another Action which is already something like toggling to object mode.

Another way is to use a weighted Bevel modifier. For that you select the edges you want to Bevel and hit Ctrl + E -> Edge Bevel Weight and pull your mouse out until they become blue. After that head to the modifier section add in a bevel modifier and change the limit method to Weight. This will give you full control over the bevel until you apply the modifer. Keep in mind tho this is non-destructive which means you cant control the individual vertices until you choose to apply it.